# How can I redirect from old domain to new one excerpt specific directories?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I've changed the domain of wordpress and would like to redirect only EC pages.(The domains are example.)

```
・Old Domain -> https://old-domain.com
・New Domain -> https://new-domain.com
```

I want to redirect all pages from old to new, except these pages.

```
・shop
・product
・cart
・checkout
```

And I wrote those on my htaccess file.

▼Old Domain（Wanna redirect **only** shop, product, cart, checkout directories to New Domain.）

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^shop(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/shop$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/product$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cart(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/cart$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^checkout(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/checkout$1 [R=301,L]
```

▼New Domain（Wanna redirect all pages to Old Domain, **excerpt** shop, product, cart, checkout directories.）

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cart/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://old-domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Both of them do not work. It seems to redirect correctly in a moment, but immediately back to **https://new-domain.com**.
Please help me to solve it.

Comment: What are "EC pages"?

Comment: The redirection rules look fine at first glance, could it be that you are looking at cached redirections? Please test again using a fresh anonymous browser window.

Comment: Hi thank you for the comments. EC pages means web shop pages. I always clear the cache and try it but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved it by myself!
The above is the correct answers I wrote on httaccess files.

▼old-domain.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^shop(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/shop$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/product$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cart(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/cart$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^checkout(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/checkout$1 [R=301,L]
```

▼new-domain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/shop/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/product/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/cart/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/checkout/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/checkout/order-received/)
RewriteRule ^$ https://old-domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why should this be different? The brackets do not make a logical difference in the matching patterns of the conditions. The only difference I can spot is the additional rule with the "order-received" path component you never mentioned in the question. So how should this answer your question?